# Double height when using position: fixed

Tags: html, css, web

When I open popup on my site from desktop, all right. But when I open popup on mobile devices, popup-overlay has double height (popup go to top of page).

```
Example of popup: http://jsfiddle.net/tb28F/
```

How can i fix it?

**Update.** Example of my problem: imgur.com/hKHjPzP

Comment: you want to be this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/tb28F/1/

Comment: @RohitAzad, I was already trying use this, but this not working

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height to the viewport height value, after adding the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And CSS:

```
.popup-overlay {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's no helping me. And I already use viewport. Example of my problem: http://imgur.com/hKHjPzP